# Replicated load balancer

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, k3s

I apologize for my inexperience, but I need to ask a question and I believe this is the right place. I set up a HA k3s cluster with 1 master and 2 replicas, but I've been told that I must put a load balancer in front of this infrastructure to avoid service disruption in case of failovers. I would like to use a high-availability configuration for the load balancer too, as I would like to avoid single points of failure. Does anybody know about open-source tools providing a high available load balancer? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on bare metal, one open source tool that implements the Load Balancer feature in kubernetes and AFAIK supports k3s is `metallb`.
Take a look at the [official documentation](https://metallb.universe.tf/) to get started.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm not talking about a tool supporting the implementation of k3s load balancer services. I'm talking about a traditional network load balancer (say, the ones you can build with nginx) with an address I can route my kubeconfig to.

Comment: Maybe clarify your use case because it's still unclear to me. You want to use if to access the kubernetes API or to access the workloads running in your kubernetes cluster?

Comment: Sure. I want to access the kubernetes API issuing e.g. a "kubectl get pods" from outside the cluster. To do so, I exported the kubeconfig to my local computer. This enables me to run e.g. "kubectl get pods" and interact with the cluster, but this way if the primary goes down I get "service unavailable". I've been told that I can solve this issue by creating a network load balancer and replacing the primary master IP in my local kubeconfig with the loadbalancer IP, so if the primary goes down the connection if forwarded to one of the replicas.